# I am trying to change the data type of date from "character" to "date", but after doing so, the year in the date format changes from 2016 to 2020

Tags: r

I am trying to change the data type of date from "character" to "date" in R, but after doing so, the year in the date format changes from 2016 to 2020. Why is this happening?
Please check below code that I am using.

```
## Creating a data frame
daily_steps <- read.csv("/cloud/project/data_files/dailySteps_merged.csv", header = TRUE)

## Current data type of "ActivityDay" is "character"
> class(daily_steps$ActivityDay)
[1] "character"

## Viewing the first six rows of the dataset
> head(daily_steps)
          Id ActivityDay StepTotal
1 1503960366   4/12/2016     13162
2 1503960366   4/13/2016     10735
3 1503960366   4/14/2016     10460
4 1503960366   4/15/2016      9762
5 1503960366   4/16/2016     12669
6 1503960366   4/17/2016      9705

## Converting the data format from character to date
> daily_steps$ActivityDay <- as.Date(daily_steps$ActivityDay, "%m/%d/%y")

## Now the data type of "ActivityDay" is "Date"
> class(daily_steps$ActivityDay)
[1] "Date"

## Viewing the first six rows of the dataset
> head(daily_steps)
          Id ActivityDay StepTotal
1 1503960366   4/12/2020     13162
2 1503960366   4/13/2020     10735
3 1503960366   4/14/2020     10460
4 1503960366   4/15/2020      9762
5 1503960366   4/16/2020     12669
6 1503960366   4/17/2020      9705
```

Appreciate your help here.

Comment: You can try change the year %y to %Y

Comment: See [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) for a list of the `%`-codes, you should be using `%Y` as AntreasStefopoulos already said.